# MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
MySQL Database Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as billing_services from billing_services_t where service_id=x ;    select * fr' at line 3
```

I am getting the above error with stored procedure,I am using.Below one is the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pn_crm_psp_billing_pnsl.`Takeoffone6`(x INT)
  BEGIN
   select * as billing_services from billing_services_t where service_id=x ;
  select * from billing_product_type_t
   ;
 END;
```

I am getting the error when I am included the **as billing_services** .Is there anything wrong in this query.

Comment: "select * as billing_services". this is the syntax error.. you can assign an alias to specific column OR table... but here you are trying to assign alias to all columns at once...

Comment: Thank you @RakeshShewale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not give alias to * you should give it after table name

```
select *  from billing_services_t as billing_services where billing_services.service_id=x ;
```